# Header in RichTextBox file gets removed

Tags: c#, file, header, richtextbox, rft

I use the following code:

```
RichTextBox rtf = new RichTextBox();
rtf.Rtf = AnswerRTF;
rtf.SaveFile(sourceFile + "/" + fileName);
```

for creating a `RichTextBox` file
but this code removes `Header` and `Footer` after creating that file.
What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that provided info is enough?

Comment: hello, i have original file  this 
[link](https://srv-store6.gofile.io/download/Pcujph/orginal%20file.PNG) 
and AnswerRTF file this 
[link](https://srv-store6.gofile.io/download/Pcujph/1.txt) 
and result return file after use coding this file 
[link](https://srv-store6.gofile.io/download/Pcujph/after%20file.PNG)

Comment: i use code remove header file 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use the following code for create rtf file when you saved rtf file in a database  :

```
            string attachFile = Path.Combine(dataDirectory, fileName);
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(attachFile, true);
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine(AnswerRTF);
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine("}");
            myStreamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you my friend